# Slugs on hierarchical taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, slug

Good day!

I found many related questions but somehow I can't apply them to my specific case. I am trying to play around with custom taxonomies and custom post type in order to obtain the following hierarchical URL structure:

```
/author-name/

/author-name/album-name/

/author-name/album-name/song-name/
```

For example:

`/chuck-berry/`: text from author page plus the archive page of type album with all the albums written by chuck berry

`/chuck-berry/st-louis-to-liverpool/`: text from album page + archive page of type song with all the songs that belong to st-louis-to-liverpool

`/chuck-berry/st-louis-to-liverpool/you-can-ever-tell`: the specific song

So every time I add a page of type author I will create a similar structure. When I create a page of type album and link it to a specific author I will add an album to that author page.

How can I obtain this result? Does it make sense in the WP framework?

Comment: There are a few possible solutions to this structure. In general though, repetition (e.g. the same author or same album) is better managed through taxonomies, rather than hierarchical post objects. Do you need extensive descriptions for each author, album and tracks? what content will you have there?

Comment: Ciao and thanks for your reply. Yes, I have data for authors, albums and songs. I am not sure whether I should use custom post types with custom taxonomies or just reuse the standard pages with a custom template.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using Pages, leaving them to more standard "static" content, and use a custom post type (eg. music).

Since you do have content on all 3 levels, you might want to use a hierarchical custom post type, where the author is the parent content, albums are the author's children and tracks are albums' children.

In general though, using custom taxonomies (eg. albums, authors) creates a more organized and readily usable structure, rather than a bulky series of parents and children.

There is also another option, using a plugin "[Enhanced Category Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-category-pages/)" that turns your terms into "real content", however it hasn't been updated in a while.